# Direct Download link for Google Drive (from dl.google.com)?

Tags: google-drive

Does anyone have the direct download link for Google Drive (Windows)?

I've been trying to piece it together by looking at the source of `https://tools.google.com/dlpage/drive/index.html` but have thus far been unsuccessful.

Various items are preventing me from using the standard download link.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I'm silly. I just needed to look at the Chrome Downloads history.

https://dl.google.com/tag/s/appguid%3D%7B3C122445-AECE-4309-90B7-85A6AEF42AC0%7D%26iid%3D%7BFC022E01-FBA5-2958-5882-A2C985D63D79%7D%26lang%3Den%26browser%3D4%26usagestats%3D0%26appname%3DGoogle%2520Drive%26needsadmin%3Dtrue/drive/googledrivesync.exe

Answer (score -1):

We can do this in two methods manual & automate.

Automate:

if you want easy to automate download then use [Google Drive Direct download link](https://ewasion-github-io.com/google-drive-direct-download-link.html).

Manual:

To get a direct download link from Google Drive.

You can follow these steps.
First, go to the file you wish to share on Google Drive.
Right-click on the file and choose "Get link" from the options.
A dialog box will appear where you can adjust the sharing settings.
Choose the appropriate access level, whether it's "Anyone with the link,"
and share the link.
Hope it works.